# ag-grid react cellRendererFramework doesn't re render when state changed

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm displaying data in ag-grid-react and grid has come conditional cell rendering based on state. Here is my code. This is working on first run and displaying "YEAH" button. when i clicked button i want to change with NOOO button

This is state

```
this.changebutton = this.changebutton.bind(this);
this.state= {
   isyes = "yes"
}
```

This is ag-grid-cell-renderer

```
cellRendererFramework: (params) => {
  return <div>
   {
     this.state.isyes === "yes" ? 
<button onClick= {() => this.changebutton()}>YEAH</button> 
: 
<button onClick= {() => this.changebutton()}>NOOOO</button>
 }

</div>

}
```

this is state changer

```
changebutton() {
     this.setState({isyes: "no" })
      console.log(this.state.isyes)
}
```

I seeing state is changing properly, But doesn't see any change of button. why?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems incomplete to check your situation. First thing that comes in mind is the expression is evaluated once (maybe, as it appears as a method of an object not directly in render function) and is never retriggered.

Also notiche that `setState()` is `async` so you **should not**:

```
this.setState({isyes: "no" });
console.log(this.state.isyes);
```

instead **you should**:

```
this.setState(
    {isyes: "no" },
    () => console.log(this.state.isyes);
);
```

Try with:

```
api.refreshCells()
```

ref: ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components

Comment: Thanks for the answer i seeing state changes immediatelly with your code. but button is not changed still

Comment: The button is not changing because the function that generates it is evaluated once, check "refresh" section at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Comment: Thanks for answer. grid.redrawRows solved refreshing problems. But i have another problem. All rows has own button that depends on isyes state. But as you can see isyes is static state. I must define state as dynamic and row based. 

i tried to this.state[ROW_ID] for dynamic state. But seems doesn't work. static state is worked but affecting all rows because of rows buttons are created by static state.